# ASP.NET/VB.NET problem solving help!

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net, controls, repeater

Got a problem I need help with. Basically I'm gonna develop a form (part of a bigger web app) that lists a load of clients and there business contact, tech contact 1, and tech contact 2.

The idea is rapid data entry. So one form shows each client with their contacts in dropdowns and I we can change each one then click a save button to do a mass save.

the database looks like this:

**tblClient**

ClientID

ClientName

BusinessContact

Tech1

Tech2

My idea was to use a repeater to format the data like this:

**Client**

Business Contact

Tech1

Tech2

**Client2**

Business Contact

Tech1

Tech2

What I'm stuck on is how to do the mass update? Can I do something like for each item in Repeater1 then do an update SQL statement? -- Jonesy

Answer (score 0):

If you use the GUI tools in VS to build a datasource with DataAdaptors and hook these into a gridview, all the code is written for you, other than calling update on your save button.

Comment: Will this save button do the whole lot in a oner? I've used the gridview update button before but i need to add in a few dropdowns. Can a gridview support dropdown lists?

Comment: A gridview can support drop downs with a bit of work.  If you tie your gridview into the datasource object, which in turn hooks into a data adaptor, then the Save just needs to call the update method on the DataAdaptor.

Comment: this has turned out to be a bit of a bugger. apprently vs sqldatasources dont support SQL 2008 :( so am having to query them in the code behind and databind the gridview and dropdowns. will this be able to work the same?

Comment: also, when I click the edit link i get this error message: The GridView 'GridView1' fired event RowEditing which wasn't handled.

Answer (score 0):

A manual approach would be to format the data into an XML block and pass it to a stored procedure, where you can then create an UPDATE statement that JOINS to the XML to perform the update in one shot.

The XML you would want to create would be similar to:

```
<ClientData>
    <Client ClientID="1" BusinessContact="..." Tech1="..." Tech2="..." />
    <Client ClientID="2" ... />
    ...
</ClientData>
```

One way to create this by using an XmlWriter and looping over your repeater to harvest the data.  In VB.NET:

```
Dim stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream
Dim settings As New System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings

settings.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1") 'This encoding handles special characters pasted in from MS Word

Dim writer As System.Xml.XmlWriter = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings)

With writer
    .WriteStartElement("ClientData")
    For Each item As RepeaterItem In myRepeater.Items
        .WriteStartElement("Client")
        .WriteAttributeString("ClientId", CType(item.FindControl("ClientIdHidden"), HtmlInputHidden).Value)
        .WriteAttributeString("BusinessContact", CType(item.FindControl("BusinessContact"), TextBox).Text)
        ...
        .WriteEndElement()
    Next
    .WriteEndElement()
    .Flush()
End With

Dim xmlString As String = writer.Settings.Encoding.GetString(stream.ToArray())
```

Then create a stored procedure that takes a parameter where you can pass in the XML:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[BulkUpdateClients]
(
    @xmlInput AS text
)
AS

DECLARE @xmlHandle int

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @xmlHandle output, @xmlInput

UPDATE c
SET
    BusinessContact = x.BusinessContact,
    Tech1 = x.Tech1,
    Tech2 = x.Tech2
FROM tblClient c
    JOIN 
    (
        SELECT
            ClientId,
            BusinessContact,
            Tech1,
            Tech2
        FROM
           OPENXML (@xmlHandle, '/ClientData/Client', 1)
           WITH
           (
               ClientId int,
               BusinessContact varchar(50),
               Tech1 varchar(50),
               Tech2 varchar(50)
           )
   ) x ON c.ClientId = x.ClientId
```

The code above hasn't been tested, but I think the general pattern is there.  I've used this technique for bulk inserts on a number of occasions.  I like it because it gets the job done in a single database operation.